# Merging XML files

Tags: qgis, merge, features, xml, combine

I am doing research about the city of Hamburg and I downloaded a dataset containing georeferenced point data of every house in Hamburg. The problem is that the dataset is made up of about 250 different XML files, all for a specific part of the city. I want to extract the features I need from each of these XML files and combine those extracted features into one XML file. Is this at all possible? If so, how should I go about doing this?

Comment: Where did you get this datasets and what is 'point data of every house'? Centroids? Adresses? If so, did you consider to download the whole ALKIS data at once (http://daten-hamburg.de/geographie_geologie_geobasisdaten/ALKIS_Liegenschaftskarte/ALKIS_Liegenschaftskarte_ausgewaehlteDaten_HH_2017-04-01.zip) and import it to a PostGIS DB? If not, consider to merge all your xml file into one (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377949/combining-multiple-xml-documents-into-one-large-one-with-a-batch-file), do your selection and then 'save as...' to gml from QGIS.

Comment: I got the dataset from the same link you mentioned above (http://daten-hamburg.de/geographie_geologie_geobasisdaten etc.) I am now using the batch method to merge the xml files. The points are indeed adresses.

Comment: If you download the adresses from http://daten-hamburg.de/geographie_geologie_geobasisdaten/ALKIS_Adressen/ALKIS_Adressen_HH_2016-09.zip you have 273.994 adresses in on gml file, which you can simply drag and drop into QGIS.

Comment: I found that one too a couple minutes ago, but I felt too ashamed to mention it. Thanks for your help though! Still gonna try and do the .bat/select method just to see how it works.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the primary question is about merging xml files together, not how to get them to display in a spatial context.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, and not too difficult in XSLT or XQuery. But the devil is in the detail: can't really help you without more specific information about the input and desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your points are adresses, consider having a look at http://daten-hamburg.de/geographie_geologie_geobasisdaten/ALKIS_Adressen/ALKIS_Adressen_HH_2016-09.zip From there you get all adresses in one gml file, which can be simply loaded into QGIS without need to merge anything:

[image]

Closeup:

[image]

Comment: You can use batch or bash copy. Copy *'xml merged.xml